# recursion? Or how to keep getting parents parent?

Tags: c#, winforms, recursion

I posted this before but had to delete the question because I explained it so horribly, sorry to those who might have read it before.  Let me be much more clear.  I have to create a winform application that allows one to copy files from one directory to another by specifying three things:

1. Where to copy from `(txtPath)`
2. What file extensions to copy (the ones you specify are the ones that are copied over) `(txtExtensions)`
3. Where to copy to `(txtArchiveTo)`

Visually it looks like this:

[image]

The copy from the txtPath to the txtArchiveTo has to match how it is copied.  That is if `txtPath` looks like the following:

```
c:\temp
  |
   -drivers.exe (file)
   -log.txt (file)
   -\Test1 (directory)
   -\Test2 (directory)
```

Then if I select for `txtArchiveTo` a folder such as `c:\backup` the result should be after my program runs it should look like this:

```
c:\backup
  |
   -\temp
      |
       -drivers.exe (file)
       -log.txt (file)
       -\Test1 (directory)
       -\Test2 (directory)
```

That is whatever is copied needs to follow the same structure...but I am having a hard time coding this because it looks as though I keep referencing `root.Parent.Parent`, etc.  Let me post some code:

The `Go` button is very basic:

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(txtPath.Text);
    WalkDirectoryTree(di);
}
```

This simply creates a directoryinfo object so I have a handle to the `txtPath` directory and calls a function `WalkDirectoryTree`.  That function looks like this:

```
 private void WalkDirectoryTree(DirectoryInfo root)
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo[] files = null;
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;

            string[] extArray = txtExtensions.Text.Split(' '); //to hold the txtExtensions as an array string { "txt" "tar" "zip" etc.. }
            string ext; //to hold the extension

            // First, process all the files directly under this folder
            try
            {
                files = root.GetFiles("*.*");
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
            {
                throw; //todo: log this later on...
            }
            catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            if (files != null)
            {
                foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in files)
                {
                    string extension = fi.Extension.ToString();
                    if (extension.IndexOf(".") > -1)
                        ext = extension.Substring(1, extension.Length-1);
                    else
                        ext = extension;

                    if (extArray.Any(s => ext.Contains(s)))
                    {    
                        //copy the file
                        if (Directory.Exists(txtArchiveTo.Text + "\\" + fi.Directory.Name))
                            {
                                //directory exists copy the files
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(txtArchiveTo.Text + "\\" + fi.Directory.Name);
                            }

                            File.Copy(fi.FullName, txtArchiveTo.Text + "\\" + fi.Directory.Name + "\\" + fi.Name);                    
                        
                        //create a shortcut pointing back to the file...
                        using (ShellLink shortcut = new ShellLink())
                        {
                            shortcut.Target = fi.FullName;
                            //shortcut.Description = "MY SHORTCUT";
                            shortcut.DisplayMode = ShellLink.LinkDisplayMode.edmNormal;
                            shortcut.ShortCutFile = fi.DirectoryName + "\\" + fi.Name + ".lnk";
                            shortcut.Save();
                        }
                    }

                }

                // Now find all the subdirectories under this directory.
                subDirs = root.GetDirectories();

                foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
                {
                    // Resursive call for each subdirectory.
                    WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo);
                }
            }            
        }
```

Please do not pay much attention to the code where I create a shortcut, etc.  That part is not the problem.  What I am having difficulty with is when I hit these lines of code:

```
 if (extArray.Any(s => ext.Contains(s)))
                        {    
                            //copy the file
                            if (Directory.Exists(txtArchiveTo.Text + "\\" + fi.Directory.Name))
                                {
                                    //directory exists copy the files
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Directory.CreateDirectory(txtArchiveTo.Text + "\\" + fi.Directory.Name);
                                }
```

The `if` simply checks to see if the extension of the file matches an extension the user has typed inside of `txtExtensions` this ensures we are only copying files with those extensions BUT within the folders they are found.  My issue is right after that if...I cannot just say:

`Directory.CreateDirectory(txtArchiveTo.Text + "\\" + fi.Directory.Name);`

The reason being is the archive folder must match the same folder path as what is being copied.  So for instance if someone selected c:\temp to search and find txt files to copy from and they selected a folder c:\backup to copy to and c:\temp had 3 subfolders (One, Two, and Three) that also contained text files.  The result would be that after my program runs (the completion of "Go") the result would be that the archive folder c:\backup would contain folders (One, Two, and Three) with the txt files inside of them, in addition, c:\backup\One\mytest.txt, etc.

I want to incorporate this in my current code, and feel I am really close but think I need to come up with some recurrision to get the right directory structure.  Please do not post me to links about MSDN on how to use Directory.CreateDirectory, or the FileInfo class, I have read these and understand them.

Comment: @DJKRAZE That is not my question...I know how to copy files recursively.  The issue is how to maintain the correct path since I am first getting files..then if a directory appears it recalls WalkDirectoryTree and that is where it can get funky because the directory needs to be at the same level as txtPath...

Comment: The current path should be held in a variable.. now if you are in that current Directory you should then hold the files based on that extension into an array or a list and iterate that list in a foreach loop within that loop then you do the copy does this make sense..?

Comment: ispiro - my question is how can I do the copying...Because as soon as I hit a new directory and "WalkDirectoryTree()" I've got a new root...basically the copy should match but go in a new location, see my existing code, what can I do there to fix it up...

Comment: Post the string value of results of run of `Directory.Exists(txtArchiveTo.Text + "\\" + fi.Directory.Name` use a small example. This way we understand how your code is working then post what you actually want.  I should point out your last paragrapth makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the destination folder in as a paramter to your walking function:

```
    private void WalkDirectoryTree(DirectoryInfo root, string DestinationFolder)
```

Then when you copy the file, you can just use the CopyTo method of the fileInfo:

```
     fi.CopyTo(DestinationFolder)
```

When calling the next method recursively, you can just add to the desintation path:

```
    foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
    {
        // Resursive call for each subdirectory.
        WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo, System.IO.Path.Combine(DestinationFolder, dirInfo.Name));
    }
```

When making the initial call, you will need to compute the output directory:

```
string path = txtPath.Text;
string outputDir = txtArchiveTo.Text
string finalDir = System.IO.Path.Combine(outputDir, path.Remove(0, System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(path).Length));

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(txtPath.Text);
WalkDirectoryTree(di, finalDir);
```

Comment: This sort of works...but imagine this structure `c:\temp\test1` as txtPath.  The `txtArchive` contains `c:\backup`, after using your code the result is `c:\backup\test1` but it should be `c:\backup\temp\test1`

Comment: @oJM86o Then you specify C:\backup\temp as the root for the initial call to WalkDirectoryTree

Comment: @JohnKoerner I understand that, but the user will select say just c:\backup.  He or she will never remember to put in c:\backup\temp.  Isnt there a way to automatically give it the first encountered folder.  Temp was just an example this changes...

Comment: @oJM86o You have to decide the rules.  I don't know your requirements.  What if the user selected c:\Program Files\SomeApp, should the output be to C:\backup\SomeApp or C:\backup\Program Files\SomeApp?  I was demonstrating the fix for the copy file issue you were having, I was not trying to provide you a complete solution.

Comment: In this case it would be `c:\backup\Program Files\SomeApp` this is where my issue lies.